# Symfony2: loading files across bundles

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, translation

I'm looking for a way to get a list of all translation/configuration files across all bundles, in a service.
The aim is to load some of the config and translation strings in a centralized place, in order to make them available to the front-end application.

All the variables extracted that way will be given to one view, so it's quite important to have this job done in one place.

What techniques are there to get a list of similar files across bundles (like files in a similar folder, with a similar name, etc...) without having to explicitely list all the bundles in the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Finder in the symfony2 component (http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html)

```
$finder->in('src/Symfony/*/*/Resources');
```